# Retrieve array of attachment IDs attached to a given Post ID

Tags: functions, function-exists

I wonder if there's a function to retreive an array containing the attachment IDs of images that are atatched to a given post. Some function like get_post_arry($pid);

The array should be ordered like

```
    ['0':'image1', '1':'image2', '2':'image3', .... etc. ]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Florian

Answer (score 0):

found a solution: thought it might be worth sharing...

```
////  We use $gallery_media as an array containing all attachment IDs that have been approved by the admin before
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'          => 'post_date',
        'order'            => 'ASC',
        'post_status' =>'any',
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        // This queries a custom field I created for media attachments – can be either 'piúblished' or 'pending'
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'attachment_status',
                'value' => 'published',
            )
        )
        ); 
    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if ( $attachments ) {
        $gallery_media = array();
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            // Check if attachment has been reviewed and custom status is "published"
            // Put together our array
            $gallery_media[] = apply_filters( 'id' , $attachment->ID );
        }
    }

// Outputs an indexed array containing attachment IDs according to our query
```

http://pastebin.com/ADVkaFvU

Comment: Click the [check mark](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G1SEk.png) to mark the answer that solved your problem as The Solution.